Combinatorics and 15-gons (pentadecagons)
Given a 15-sided polygon, is it possible to write one of the integers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 in each of its vertices such that: by choosing two different integers from 1 to 6 at random, there is always a side of this polygon with those two integers on its vertices?
I'm not trying to mathematically prove that it is possible, but more focused on finding an example layout.
Edit: It is not possible given a 15-gon and 6 integers. But is there a connection between an existing theorem or proof and the greatest amount of integers for a n-gon?

This works for 10-sided polygons with the numbers "1,2,3,4,5" : See the sequence:
1-> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 2 -> 4 -> 1 -> 3 -> 5 . It only works for odd numbers (eg 3,  5), not for even ones (eg. 6).

No, it is not possible.
To see this, suppose it were possible and fix a good labeling.  In that labeling, let $a_i$ be the number of times $i$ appears at a vertex.  Since any given $i\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ needs to be a vertex  in at least $5$ edges, we need $a_i≥3$ for all $i$.  But $\sum a_i=15$, which is then impossible.
Note:  the same argument shows that, in fact, we need at least $18$ sides, since $a_i≥3\implies n=\sum a_i≥18$.

Your proof looks logical, but what about the fact there needs to be 15 connections. 1 connects to 2,3,4,5,6; 2 to 3,4,5,6; 3 to 4,5,6; 4 to 5;6 and 5 to 6? Is this a kind of problem where the proof goes against intuition?

I don't understand.  The proof is the proof.  I don't think it defies intuition.  I think it is natural.

Your argument shows that the assignment is impossible for an $n-$gon with $n<15$, as you need at least $\binom 62=15$ edges.  However, ruling out $n≤14$ does not immediately tell you that $n=15$ will work, and the argument I provided shows that in fact it does not.  In fact, the argument I described shows that you need $n≥18$, since $a_i≥3\implies n=\sum a_i≥18$.  Again, this does not prove that $n=18$ will suffice, just that $n<18$ will not.  In fact, $n=18$ does work but proving it pretty much requires you to exhibit a good labeling for an $18-$gon.

Thank you. The proof is perfectly clear. I also found that by labeling for a 18-gon, you get 15 unique pairs and 3 pairs that repeat twice.

First, given $k$ labels $\{1,\ldots,k\}$, it is clear that you need an $n$-gon with $n\ge k \lceil (k-1)/2 \rceil$ for there to be such a labelling. One can show this using the same argument @lulu used in his answer for $k=6$.
This is also sufficient as explained below. That is, I give an explicit way to construct a good labelling of an $n$-gon with $k$ labels whenever $n$ satisfies the above inequality.
Consider the complete graph on $k$ vertices, denoted as $K_k$. Label the vertices from $1$ to $k$. Each vertex has $k-1$ neighbours. So, when $k$ is odd, there is an Eulerian cycle in this graph. Now given an $n$-gon with $n=\binom{k}2$, label the vertices of that $n$-gon using the labels on the vertices along the above Eulerian cycle. This gives a good labelling that satisfies your requirements. (This is precisely how it works in the example in @user3257842's comment.)
When $k$ is even, there is no Eulerian cycle in $K_k$, but consider the graph obtained by removing a perfect matching from $K_k$. That is, remove the $k/2$ edges given by $(1,k)$, $(2,k-1)$, $(3,k-2)$, so on. The resulting graph again has only even-degree vertices, and hence has an Eulerian cycle. Now let $n = \frac{k^2}2 = \binom{k}2 + \frac{k}2 = n' + k-1$, where $n'=\binom{k}2 - \frac{k}2 + 1$. Use the Eulerian cycle to label $n'$ consecutive vertices of the $n$-gon. Then, label the remaining $k-1$ vertices using the removed perfect matching. More specifically, the labelling is given by
$$
\underbrace{1\rightarrow\cdots\rightarrow1}_{\text{Eulerian cycle}}\rightarrow k \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow (k-1) \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow (k-2) \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow \tfrac{k}2 \rightarrow (\tfrac{k}2+1).
$$
Therefore, for even $k$, there is a good labelling for any $n \ge k^2/2$.

Edit: The OP asked for an explicit good labelling of the smallest $n$-gon with $k=6$ labels. From the above answer, the smallest $n$ for which this is possible is $n=k^2/2 = 18$. An explicit labelling, found from the above Eulerian cycle construction, is given below:
$$
1\rightarrow5\rightarrow6\rightarrow4\rightarrow5\rightarrow3\rightarrow6\rightarrow2\rightarrow4\rightarrow1\rightarrow3\rightarrow2\rightarrow1\rightarrow6\rightarrow2\rightarrow5\rightarrow3\rightarrow4.
$$

Thanks for the detailed answer. However, I'm not looking for any generalizations. Since I'm not quite familiar with graph theory or Eulerian cycles, could you please provide me the sequence that satisfies my original requirements with the fewest possible integers in the sequence?

I'm more interested in finding the smallest n for fixed k (in this case k=6)

@MattiasJoosepTammaru. I have added an explicit good labelling of $18$-gon using $k=6$ labels. No smaller $n$-gon has a good labelling with $k=6$ labels.
